# Display different websites with same URL

Tags: web, dns

I want to display different website for my customers outside US, how this can be achieved without using sub-folder.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you did not explain your scenario.I suggest you explain to get better answers.

Anyways, If internationalization is what you want then you can rely on any CMS like Wordpress, Joomla etc and all of your content will be saved in Database. This way you will not have any subfolders and still a site for different countries. There is more to it in detail but basically that's the idea.

Obviously the above scenario applies if you are using a CMS.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, actually our case is that we want to display some pages to our US clients but not to the clients from rest of world, your database option is good, but is there any option that our single domain point to multiple servers ?

Answer (score 0):

If your website is in Joomla. I think there is a plugin.module which separates page regionally. Anyway, whats the URL of the website.